# Deklination von „gleich“

Tags: adjective, declension

In *Wörter zur Wahl* gibt es eine Frage:

> Sind Sie anderer Ansicht? Nein, ich bin der ______. (gleich)

In der Lösung steht: *gleichen*.

Ich glaubte, dass die Lösung *gleiche* sein muss, weil man Nominativ benutzen muss. Also: *der gleiche Ansicht* und nicht *der gleichen Ansicht*.

Wo ist mein Fehler?

Comment: Dein Fehler ist, dass der Nominativ falsch ist. Nominativ wäre »Sind Sie *andere* Ansicht?« »Nein, ich bin *die* gleiche Ansicht.« Femininer Genitiv kann mit maskulinem Nominativ schon verwechselt werden ;)

Comment: Ich kenne dieses Buch oder was auch immer es ist nicht, aber ich wette, es heißt "Wörter **zur** Wahl", oder? Ich hab das mal gefixed, weil mit "zum" klingt es doch arg merkwürdig.

Comment: @Jan Richtig, aber ich fürchte, ohne einen Hinweis auf Deklinatstypen wird das nicht viel helfen.

Comment: @Matthias Deswegen auch nur Kommentar und nicht Antwort.

Comment: Du kannst schon daran, dass "Ansicht" weiblich ist, erkennen, dass es sich hier nicht um den Nominativ handeln kann.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es ist kein Nominativ, sondern es handelt sich dabei um einen so genannten prädikativen Genitiv, d.h. um einen Genitiv, der über das Verb *sein* mit dem Subjekt verbunden ist. Daher muss es heißen:

> Ich bin der gleichen (Ansicht).

Es gibt [laut Dr. Bopp](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2014/09/15/der-fall-in-der-meinung-sein/) nur eine Handvoll Wendungen, in denen diese spezielle Art vorkommt, unter anderem:

> der/gleicher/anderer Ansicht sein
>   der/gleicher/anderer Meinung sein
>   guten Mutes, guter Laune, guter Dinge sein
>   gleichen Alters sein
>   guter Hoffnung sein
>   voller Erwartung, voller Hoffnung, voller Spannung sein
>   des Glaubens sein
>   reinen Herzens sein
>   bäuerlicher Herkunft sein
>   natürlichen Ursprungs sein

Comment: Sicher, dass es ein prädikativer Genitiv ist? Andere Grammatiken (erster Google-Fund: https://books.google.de/books?id=O-ANAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100#v=onepage&q&f=false) sagen, es sei ein Genitivus Possesivus, was auch inhaltlich durchaus passt ("Ich" besitzt eine Ansicht).

Comment: Naja, das allgemeine Schema ist in diesem fall ja *[wessen] sein*, daher scheint mir der prädikative Genitiv passender.

Comment: Ich kenne prädikativen Genitiv als Teil eines festen Verbmusters ("sich dessen erinnern"), und "sein" ist sowieso eines Ausnahme ("X ist Y", beide Nominativ), deshalb wäre ich mir da nicht so sicher. Vielleicht sollte ich eine Frage daraus machen. :-)